# Syntax error while using variables in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax

This might look like a silly question so pardon me. I was trying to write a `trigger` in mysql and am constantly getting `#1064` which, I believe is a syntax error. Here is the sql for the `trigger`:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER lh_insert 
AFTER INSERT ON leaderboard_forheap
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE leaderboard_len TINYINT;
  INSERT INTO leaderboard_heap VALUES (NEW._id);
  CALL check_len(leaderboard_len);

  IF leaderboard_len > 1 THEN
    -- swim
    DECLARE k, comp TINYINT;
    SET k = leaderboard_len;

    CALL comp_row(k, FLOOR(k/2), comp);

    WHILE (k > 1 AND comp = -1) DO
      CALL exch_row(k, FLOOR(k/2));
      SET k = FLOOR(k/2);
      CALL comp_row(k, FLOOR(k/2), comp);
    END WHILE;

  END IF;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

The procedures `check_len, comp_row and exch_row` are working as expected independently. The syntax error is reported on the line with the declaration of `k, comp`. Here is the error string:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE k, comp TINYINT;
    SET k = leaderboard_len;

    SET k = leader' at line 11
```

I will really appreciate any help regarding this. Thanks.

Comment: The error is from the previous statement, the `DECLARE`. All DECLARE should be in the start, before any other statements.

Comment: Or add a BEGIN END inside the IF (after THEN and until END iF). The DECLARE would be fine, if it after a BEGIN.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thanks a lot. The trigger was finally created without any error.